# Python: reshaping matrix to vector of specific form

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 2x4 matrix of the form:

```
m = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8]]
```

an I'm trying to get an 8x1 vector of the form:

```
m_new = [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
```

Would the reshape() function be able to do something like this? Using

```
m_new = m.reshape(8,1)
```

unfortunately doesn't seem to do the job, but hopefully there are other settings in reshape that can achieve this.

Comment: Add a transpose, `m.T.reshape(8,1)`

Comment: Is `m` a numpy array, a numpy matrix, or a list of lists? And what does "doesn't seem to do the job" mean? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @abarnert, yes, it would be nice if he said what wasn't right.  But he does give a desired result which is different from the simple reshape, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.  Hence the deduction that he needs some sort of reordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `order` parameter, which can be applied to almost any method `numpy` uses to flatten multidimensional arrays.

[From the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

> **order : {‘C’, ‘F’, ‘A’}, optional**
>
> - ‘F’ means to read / write the elements using Fortran-like index order, with the first index changing fastest, and the last index changing slowest.

**Setup**

```
m = np.arange(1, 9).reshape(-2, 4)
```

**Examples:**

```
m.reshape(8, order='F')

m.flatten(order='F')

m.ravel(order='F')
```

All result in:

```
array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8])
```